# how do I stretch a letter S of an already existing font as smoothly as possible across a large page?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, fonts

The font is called Anton and the S needs to be stretched to a large page, I already tried illustrator and indesign but can't figured it out...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you just select the letter using the Selection Tool (V), and stretch it in Illustrator by clicking and dragging the centre edge handles? [see example](https://imgur.com/xIZCmKx).

Comment: Just make the font size bigger? What exactly do you mean by “stretched to a large page”?

Comment: hi Billy, I already tried that but it didn't formed perfectly

Comment: @Julie What do you mean by "formed perfectly"?  Why isn't it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If by "smoothly" you mean "proportionally", then make sure you hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you drag the handles to enlarge a text object.

For a more accurate alignment to specific page margins, it can help if you convert the `S` to outlines, which removes the ability to futher edit the text box, but assuming you don't need that, then you can scale the `S` better using snap to page grid or snap to guides.

Comment: The OP asks about "stretching" the letter though.  That would imply non-proportional scaling. I think we need more information to answer this properly though, it's a bit ambiguous. Also it's not clear what problem the OP is having. Adjusting the size of a letter, proportionally or not, is fairly simnple.

Comment: So for more information, I have a word that I need to stretch across a whole A1 page, but because to do this I made outlines for the other letters of this and then used the direct select tool to extend them across the whole page, but I can't do this with the S (probably because of all those curves) but was wondering how best to do this and if there were any tips or other ways...?

Answer (score 0):

On Illustrator, you can also do Object >> Expand to change it to a compound path, and then change many factors of the letter via the anchor points, path, different tools, or just the selection tool and dragging the sides to change the width/height. If you'd like to keep the proportion exact, then hold shift and drag a corner. That would be the same for if you keep it as text. Hope this helps.